# How to make the search form without the search button?

Tags: css, drupal-7, search-form

This question is related to CSS/HTML and drupal web development. I am developing website using Drupal 7. And by default `Drupal` provides the `Search form` (as shown in image) with input text box and button next to it. How can I remove the that search button and make it like just text input box, for example you can see the `search form` of `stackoverflow`. So by this there is no need for clicking the button, just write text and enter. Thanks

[image: Drupal default search form]

Note: Drupal is the content management system. And why I am asking this question here as solution is related to CSS/HTML.

Comment: could you provide the full markup of this form?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to get that part, it is a core module and there is a file under htdocs/drupal7/modules/search/ and under search module file there is so many files, and which part to take. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide submit button but keep the auto submit on enter possibility you can just hide the submit button with css:

```
#edit-custom-search-blocks { //replace this selector with ID of your submit button
      position: absolute;
      top: -999px;
      left: -999px;
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
}
```

You can place it in your default CSS file. (then clear the Drupal cache)

Comment: If you know can you let me know how to add that word "search" inside that input box by css, if it is possible by css, If it is too different, I will make new question.

Comment: With CSS not really possible.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for answers though.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the search form by implementing the `YOURTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter` in your theme. By putting `#access` on `false`, you will disable rendering of the button on the form.

```
function YOURTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#access'] = false;
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide me, to which file, which code needs to be put. Sorry, I am not too much familiar with codes. Or can you provide the link so I can read there to implement the code and do it. Very thanks.

Comment: Are you using a theme (under sites/all/[your_theme_name]) ? There should be a file called `template.php` where you need to add the hook, don't forget to clear cache when adding this code.

Comment: Yes, it is there only. let me give you full path, MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/"my_theme_name". I am currently developing on local environment.

Comment: Create a `template.php` file (if it doesn't exist already) under your `my_theme_name` folder and add the given code (by replacing `YOURTHEME` with you theme name) and clear cache

Comment: Well, it is not displaying the button that what we needed, that is good, but along with that it stopped searching, after I type any keyword and Enter, it is not searching at all. Any change.